# how should write Email content (Message) in json file

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using textarea to bind the Email content from json file. In json file If I write the content with value like ["content":
"Hi,
Test Email has been received successfully.
warm Regards,
System Administrator
"] json file showing wrong format and showing error. I want to bind this content to textarea. How should I form this Email content in json file.

Json file:

```
 "EmailMessages": [
        {
            "key": "New User Registration",
            "value": "1",
            "subject": "Registration confirmation for #ProjectName",
            "content":"Hi user,
####ProjectName Test Email has been received successfully.
Warm Regards,
System Administrator."           
        }]
```

My need is I want to fetch the email content from json file and display it in to the textarea.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the json using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). It will give you the email object (Object Array, if more than one email messages). You will then fetch the content from object using dot operator.

```js
var json_string = '{"EmailMessages":[' +
'{"key":"1","value":"Doe", "subject":"hello", "content":"Hi everyone" }]}';
var text = JSON.parse(json_string);
var textArea = document.getElementById("emailMessage");
textArea.innerHTML = text.EmailMessages[0].content;
```

```html
<textarea id="emailMessage"></textarea>
```